# PHP - Form error alerts displays on page load

Tags: php, forms

i am a newbee and just learning along the way. I have two forms on a page (I have only shown one of them as the other form is the same code with different variables). Both their error messages display on page load. How can I stop this?

I have read multiple posts regarding this but I still cannot find a solution.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['Update'])) {
        $c_fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $c_lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $c_email = $_POST['email'];
        $c_phone = $_POST['phone'];

        // Save $_POST to $_SESSION
        //query

        $insert_det = "INSERT INTO  Cus_acc_details(CUS_Fname,CUS_Lname,Cus_Email,CUS_Phone) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY 
            UPDATE
            Cus_acc_details.CUS_Fname = '$c_fname',
            Cus_acc_details.Cus_Lname = '$c_lname',
            Cus_acc_details.Cus_Email = '$c_email',
            Cus_acc_details.CUS_Phone = '$c_phone'";

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_det);
        //new
        // $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c);
        //debugging
        //$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c)  or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi', $c_fname, $c_lname, $c_email, $c_phone);

        /* execute query */
        $r = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        // if inserted echo the following messges
        if ($r) {
            echo "<script> alert('Saved')</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<b>Oops! we have an issu </b>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What error does it display ? beside the huge SQL injection issue here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `else` after your `if (isset($_POST['Update']))`. Inside that else you are displaying errors as if the user tried to submit the form. `$_POST['Update']` will *only* be set if the user tried to submit the form. Move that else inside your if:

```
if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {

    /* a bunch of code to insert into the DB */
    // if inserted echo the following messges
    if ($r) {
        echo "<script> alert('Saved')</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<b>Oops! we have an issu </b>";
    }
}
```

#### In Addition:

The commenter is right. You are at risk for SQL Injection. Please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help and explaining my mistake.

Comment: @jerneva no problem! See my "In Addition" edit to my answer though. The code you are writing is unsafe. Putting input received from the user directly into an query like that leaves you very vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you, i am very new to this so this whole injection thing is a new concept. However, i will have a read and try and gain a understanding

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your else statement is running every time the variable `$_POST['Update']` is not set.

One way to fix this is to move your error message inside your form checking code.  Something like this would work:

```
if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {

    /* unchanged code snipped */

    if ($r) {
        echo "<script> alert('Saved')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<b>Oops! we have an issu </b>";
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!